# Why is my TryParse code not working in C#?

Tags: c#, while-loop, tryparse

There is some problem in my while loop, and I don't know what the problem is:

```
double d = 0;

while (!Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), d <= 20 && d >= 1, out d))
{
    Console.WriteLine("The number is incorrect, please write in again");
}
```

Comment: For this kind of thing (request inputs until user follows the rules) a do/while loop is the ideal construct. Also the only "price" for putting a lot of things into one line, is having a *heck* of a time debugging it. Some temporary variables to split this over multiple lines, and it becomes instantly readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
double d = 0;

while (!Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out d) && d <= 20 && d >= 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The number is incorrect, please write in again");
}
```

Like this. You accidentally passed the `d <= 20 && d >= 1` as an argument for the `TryParse`, instead of using it as an additional condition for the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're misunderstanding tryparse, d is set after try parse, then you can compare it, you have put the boundaries check in the arguments of try parse:

```
while (!Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var d) || d <= 20 && d>=1)
{    //you first check if you can parse it, and after parse is true, check if value is in your boundaries
     Console.WriteLine("The number is incorrect, please write in again");
}
```